# i want to add the following from a list but the result only concatinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, addition

## Sample value of n is 5

```
    n = input("Enter a No: ")
    n = "{0}+{0}{0}+{0}{0}{0}".format(n)
    n = n.split("+")
    a=n[0] 
    b=n[1]
    c=n[2] 
    n = (a + b + c) 
    print(n)
```

## Expected Result : 615

Comment: Use the eval() function to evaluate a python statement in a string. `eval("{0}+{0}{0}+{0}{0}{0}".format(5))`

Comment: `eval` is too much here, it's very dangerous function and I'd prohibit it for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this.

```
n = input("Enter a No: ")
n = "{0}+{0}{0}+{0}{0}{0}".format(n)
out=sum([int(i) for i in n.split('+')])
```

---

if you want only the first three elements to be added then use this.

```
out_3=sum([int(i) for i in n.split('+')[:4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

After splitting n is a list of strings, you should cast them to int.

```
n = input("Enter a No: ")
n = "{0}+{0}{0}+{0}{0}{0}".format(n)
n = n.split("+")
a=int(n[0])
b=int(n[1])
c=int(n[2])
n = (a + b + c) 
print(n)
```

And if necessary add try/except to handle correctly situations when not a valid number would be passed.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add 1 extra line in your code and it should be running.

You need to convert all the elements in your list to `int` for performing addition.

Try this :

```
n = input("Enter a No: ")
n = "{0}+{0}{0}+{0}{0}{0}".format(n)
n = n.split("+")

n = list(map(int, n))

a=n[0] 
b=n[1]
c=n[2] 
n = (a + b + c) 
print(n)
```

Comment: why do i have to make a list again in line 5

Comment: Yes correct. Good catch. It's not needed there you can just use `map`. But this also wont throw error.

Comment: Edited that. Only `map` will also do the same since it was already a list.

Comment: This throws a error`n = map(int,n) ` **TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable**

Comment: `In[51]: n = 5
In[52]: n = "{0}+{0}{0}+{0}{0}{0}".format(n)
   ...: n = n.split("+")
   ...: 
   ...: n = map(int, n)
   ...: a=n[0] 
   ...: b=n[1]
   ...: c=n[2] 
   ...: n = (a + b + c) 
   ...: print(n)
615`

Comment: It runs fine on python 2.7

Comment: @PrashantKumar maybe OP is running on python-3.x. And consider upgrading. python 2 is retired already. https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: It was not mentioned in the tag. Anyways looks like the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here, how you should do it:

```
n = input("Enter a No: ")
n = "{0}+{0}{0}+{0}{0}{0}".format(n)
n = list(map(int, n.split("+")))
print(sum(n))
```

I have used [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to convert a list of string to a list of int and [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to sum all the elements of the list. I assume you need to sum all the elements of your list. If you want to sum only first three elements, then:

```
a=n[0] 
b=n[1]
c=n[2] 
n = (a + b + c) 
print(n)
```

**Note:** If you are using latest version of Python, then `n = map(int, n)` will return a TypeError: `'map' object is not subscriptable`. You need to explicitly convert object returned by map to a list.